# objective C - Generate string by tapping sprites, is this possible?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocos2d-iphone, sprite

I will describe the problem, I have sprites that are all letters of the alphabet, and I wonder how I can do that when you touch the letters form a word and I can generate a string that word and through it to compare with a string that have a plist. I need any idea that might help me, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is possible. One way to test for touches is by using the CCTouchDispatcher.

### Overview

1. Determine which class will monitor for touches of your letter sprites.
2. Make the class a delegate of CCTargetedTouchDelegate.
3. Add code to the class to register with the CCTouchDispatcher.
4. Add code to the class to unregister with the CCTouchDispatcher.
5. Add the touch callback methods to your class. In the touch callback methods, you must add code for determining which sprite was touched.

### Register and unregister from Dispatcher

```
[[CCTouchDispatcher sharedDispatcher] addTargetedDelegate:self priority:0 swallowsTouches:YES];
[[CCTouchDispatcher sharedDispatcher] removeDelegate:self];
```

### CallBack Methods To Implement

```
- (BOOL)ccTouchBegan:(UITouch *)touch withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
- (void)ccTouchMoved:(UITouch *)touch withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
- (void)ccTouchEnded:(UITouch *)touch withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
```

### Example Code For Testing If Touch In Sprite

```
- (BOOL) isTouch:(UITouch *)touch InSprite:(CCSprite *)sprite 
{
    CGPoint touchLocation = [touch locationInView: [touch view]];
    touchLocation = [[CCDirector sharedDirector] convertToGL: touchLocation];

    CGPoint localLocation = [sprite convertToNodeSpace:touchLocation];
    CGRect spriteRect = [sprite textureRect];
    spriteRect.origin = CGPointZero;

    if(CGRectContainsPoint(spriteRect, localLocation))
    {
        return YES;
    }

    return NO;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it will be more simple to use CCMenuItem (it can also be created from sprite) because it's already touchable. Everything you have to do is to specify a function will be called, when CCMenuItem is touched.

Take a look at the official programming guide:
http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/wiki/doku.php/prog_guide:lesson_3._menus_and_scenes